# NxN matrix determinant recursion issue

Tags: c, math, recursion, matrix

im currently trying to write a program to find the determinant for an NxN matrix but im having an issue with  recursion for N larger than 2. Basically from what i can tell, it isn't doing it, it just runs the function once as using my debug option shows that the function runs through the columns but the order never goes down, and it then gives me zero for my determinant no matter what. Ive tried looking all over the place for any idea as to what im doing wrong but i cant seem to find any answers, ive even found examples which do basically the same thing as me and using them gives me zero no matter what as well, so im very confused :(. id be very grateful if someone could have a quick look through my code and tell me where im being an idiot! (sorry about the formatting, it looks ok in my editor but i cant seem to get the hang of it on here)

Code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


double det(double **mat, int order);


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{  


   FILE* input; 
   int row,column,N;
   double **matrix;
   N=3;
   matrix=(double**)malloc(N*sizeof(double));

   input=fopen("matrix.dat", "r");
   if(input !=(FILE*) NULL)
   {

      for(row=0; row<N; row++) 
      { 
     matrix[row]=(double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
  }
  for(row=0; row<N; row++) 
  {
        printf("| ");
        for(column=0; column<N; column++)   
        {  
          fscanf(input,"%lf ", &matrix[row][column]); 
      printf("%g ", matrix[row][column]);
    }
     if(row != (N/2))
         { 
       printf("|\n");
         }
         else
         {

           printf("|= %lf \n", det(matrix, N) );
     }
 }
 return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }

 else
 { 
  printf("*********************ERROR*********************\n");
  printf("** Cannot open input file 'matrix.dat' make  **\n");
  printf("** sure file is present in working directory **\n");
  printf("***********************************************\n");

  return(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

}

double det(double **mat, int order)
{
 int debug;
 double cofact[order], determinant, **temp;
 determinant = 0;
 debug=0;

 if(order==1)
 {
  determinant=mat[0][0];

  if(debug==1)
  {
    printf("order 1 if\n");
  }
 }
  else if(order==2)
 {
 determinant= ((mat[0][0]*mat[1][1])-(mat[0][1]*mat[1][0]));

 if(debug==1)
 {
   printf("order 2 if\n");
     }
  }
 else
 {

  int column, rowtemp, coltemp, colread;
  for (column=0; column<order; column++) 
  {
  /* Now create an array of size N-1 to store temporary data used for calculating minors */
     temp= malloc((order-1)*sizeof(*temp)); 
    for(rowtemp=0; rowtemp<(order-1); rowtemp++)
  {
    /* Now asign each element in the array temp as an array of size N-1 itself */
    temp[rowtemp]=malloc((order-1)*sizeof(double));
  }
  for(rowtemp=1; rowtemp<order; rowtemp++)
  {
    /* We now have our empty array, and will now fill it by assinging row and collumn values    from the original mat with the aprroriate elements excluded */
       coltemp=0;
      for(colread=0; colread<order; colread++)
      {
        /* When the collumn of temp is equal to the collumn of the matrix, this indicates this row should be exlcuded and is skiped over */
        if(colread==column)
        {
          continue;
        }
        temp[rowtemp-1][coltemp] = mat[rowtemp][colread];
        coltemp++;
      }

   }
  if(debug==1)
  {
    printf("column =%d, order=%d\n", column, order);
  }
  determinant+=(mat[0][column]*(1 - 2*(column & 1))*det(temp, order-1));
}   

 }  
 return(determinant);   

 }
```

Comment: The formatting is awful. Please, make it look pretty. Why should anyone bother to read it if you don't bother to write it cleanly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temp= (double **)malloc((order-1)*sizeof(double));
```

This will not cause a crash as long as `sizeof(double*) <= sizeof(double)`, which is the case on the usual 32 or 64-bit systems, but it is conceptually wrong. You are allocating space for an array of `double*`, so the factor should be `sizeof(double*)` or, better since it is invariant when the type changes, `sizeof *temp`,

```
temp = malloc((order-1) * sizeof *temp);
```

(And you don't need to cast the result of `malloc` in C, it is even better not to, since the cast could hide errors like forgetting to `#include <stdlib.h>`.)

The same holds for the allocation

```
matrix=(double**)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
```

in `main`.

In the calculation of the determinant,

```
         for(coltemp=0; coltemp<order; coltemp++)
         {
           for(colread=0; colread<order; colread++)
               {
               /* When the collumn of temp is equal to the collumn of   the matrix, this indicates this row should be exlcuded and is skiped over */
               if(colread==column)
               {
                continue;
               }
          temp[rowtemp-1][coltemp] = mat[rowtemp][colread];
          coltemp++;
            }
        }
```

You are looping twice through the columns, once for `coltemp == 0`, and then in the inner loop, `coltemp` is incremented `order-1` times, so the inner loop runs a second time with `coltemp == order-1` at the start. Then `coltemp` is again incremented multiple times in the loop, and you're writing out of bounds of the allocated memory.

The outer loop should be removed, `coltemp = 0;` and the inner loop are what you need.

```
pow(-1,column))
```

is not a good way to determine a sign.

```
(1 - 2*(column & 1))
```

is faster than a call to `pow`.

Finally, in `main`

```
for(row=0; row<N; row++) 
 {
    printf("| ");
    for(column=0; column<N; column++)   
    { 
          fscanf(input,"%lf ", &matrix[row][column]); 
          printf("%g ", matrix[row][column]);
    }
    if(row != (N/2))
    { 
    printf("|\n");
    }
    else
    {

            printf("|= %lf \n", det(matrix, N) );
    }
 }
```

You are printing the determinant at row `N/2`, which looks nice, but at that time, you have not yet scanned in the entire matrix, so rows `N/2 + 1` to `N-1` contain uninitialised data, which is not unlikely to be all zeros. If you change the `if (row != N/2)` to `if (row != N-1)`, it will work, however, the proper way to handle it is to separate the scanning of the matrix from the computation and the printing. These are all independent operations that should be handled in their own separate functions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, ive done those changes but my program is still giving me zero for the determinant no matter what matrix i give it.. ive updated the code in the question.

Comment: yes it works!!! thank you so much!, you have no idea how stressed i have been getting with this bloody thing haha.